# Exif only returning lat & lon as whole numbers

Tags: android, exif

Through my app I upload images to a database.  With the images I want to capture the location the image was taken by using the exif data. When I tested on my phone the lat and lon did upload but only to a rounded positive number.

When I'm expecting a location of Lat = 52.4 and lon = -1.9 im actually getting lat = 52 and lon 1

Here is my code; lat and lon are both String:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(mainMenu.filename);    
lat = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
lon = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
```

My database values for holding the lat and lon are doubles and I've also tried float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html), shouldn't you instead be using the [getLatLong(float[] output)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#getLatLong%28float%5B%5D%29) method?

```
float[] latLong = new float[2];
if (exif.getLatLong(latLong)) {
    // latLong[0] holds the Latitude value now.
    // latLong[1] holds the Longitude value now.
}
else {
    // Latitude and Longitude were not included in the Exif data.
}
```

Comment: how would i then assign say the lat to my string lat?

Comment: I am misunderstanding you somewhere; Aren't your database values doubles or floats?  Why do you need strings?  Anyway, I really don't know java well, but couldn't you just use `Float.toString(latLong[0])`?